# Open SAS .egp file to view code without having SAS installed

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

Is there any solution to open SAS .egp file without having SAS installed on my pc? I need to open project.egp to check my old code but I don't have SAS anymore. Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A .egp file is a zipped set of xml files (and other things).  If you change the extension to .zip, you can open it with any unzipping program, and see the contents.  It is possible to extract programs and such from there at that point, though it's not necessarily easy to do as it's fairly messy.

Answer (score -1):

.EGP files contains no code, it's just their possible execution order that might be showing.
You need to open the .SAS files imported in the EGP to see the code and to open a .SAS file just use any text editor!

Comment: This is not true. See the accepted answer. `.egp` files are essentially zipped folders containing all the code for the program. the `.sas` files are IN the `.egp` file.

Comment: It will embed code if you choose the option to embed your code and then your code is no longer on your system but then inside the EGP

Comment: Sure - it's possible to view external `.sas` files in SAS Enterprise Guide. However, this question is about opening an `.egp` file to view the contents inside, because *they often store code inside.* Your answer to this question is that `.egp` files don't contain code and *just* contain an execution order. This is not true.

Comment: Interestingly, not only embedded code, but *not* embedded code is *also* in the .egp (the most recent version).

Comment: Hi ! I 'm happy to report that indeed uzipping the file shows embeded content and you can read the program !!

Answer (score -3):

You can try to open it in [Easy Grade Pro 4.0.3](https://easy-grade-pro.en.uptodown.com/windows)

Comment: Easy Grade Pro is a program for teachers, not one for SAS procs.

Comment: The file ending refers to SAS Enterprise Guide